# Tcl read first line of a csv file

Tags: csv, scripting, tcl

I am trying to parse a CSV to check if one of the headers is present.
Sometimes I'd expect a fifth colomn with arbitraryHead

```
date   time   value  result arbitraryHead 
val1   d1      10     fail
val2   d2      15     norun
```

---

I was trying to read the first line then print it. But that is not working...
How can I read the first line and print all the headers?

```
set fh [open $csv_file r]
set data [list]
set line [gets $fh line]
lappend data [split $line ,]
close $fh
foreach x $data {
    puts "$x\n"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading a CSV file, it's best to use the [csv package in Tcllib](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html), as that handles all the awkward edge cases in that format.

In particular, `csv::split` is *especially* useful (along with `csv::join` when creating a CSV file). Or the various functions that act as wrappers around it. Here's how you'd use it in your case

```
package require csv

set fh [open $csv_file r]
# Your data appears to be actually tab-separated, not comma-separated...
set data [csv::split [gets $fh] "\t"]
close $fh

foreach x $data {
    puts "$x\n"
}
```

---

Your actual immediate bug was this:

```
set line [gets $fh line]
```

The two-argument form of `gets` writes the line it reads into the variable named in the second argument, and returns the length of line read (or -1 on failure to read a complete line, which can be useful in complex cases that aren't important here). You're *then* assigning that value to the same variable with `set`, losing the string that was written there. You should instead use *one* of the following (except that you should use a properly-tested package for reading CSV files):

```
gets $fh line
```

```
set line [gets $fh]
```

The one-argument form of `gets` returns the line it read, which can make it harder to distinguish errors but is highly convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest you can do is string match operation, just look for the desired header you wanted to check.

As requested in the following code I am checking "arbitraryHead"

```
set fh [open $csv_file r]
set contents [read $fh ]

foreach x $contents {
    if {[string match "*arbitraryHead*" $x]} {
        puts "HEAD FOUND"
    }
}
close $fh
```

Hope this address your issue